# ScrollIntoView as Top DataGridItem

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid

I have a method that selects a `DataGridItem` and uses `ScrollIntoView`. It looks like this;

```
foreach (var item in contractDataGrid.Items.OfType<ContractModel>())
{
    if (item.ID == contractID)
    {
        contractDataGrid.SelectedItem = item;
        contractDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
        break;
    }
}
```

This does "ScrollIntoView" onto the expected item but it sets it at around the middle of the current view of `DataGridItems`. Is there a way to modify this method so that the `DataGrid` is scrolled in a way that makes the `ScrollIntoView(item)` the top item in the `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 0):

It's the code I'm using and hope this helps..

To scrollintoview to the first item,

```
contractDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(contractDataGrid.Items.GetItemAt(0));
```

And to scrollintoview to the last item,

```
    contractDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(contractDataGrid.Items.GetItemAt(contractDataGrid.Items.Count- 1));
```